# Why is my computer not noticing the graphics cards I've plugged into it?

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, pci-express

I am attempting to connect a couple of "Radeon RX 480" graphics cards to my [BIOSTAR TB85](http://www.biostar.com.tw/app/en/mb/introduction.php?S_ID=734) motherboard via PCIe risers.

I have installed `Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS` onto the machine, plugged the graphics cards into the PCIe ports via risers, and followed [AMD's instructions](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Installation-Instructions-for-amdgpu-Graphics-Stacks.aspx) to install the graphics card driver `amdgpu-pro`.

However, my machine does not appear to have any knowledge of the graphics cards' presence there. For one thing, the `clinfo` program does not appear to notice the cards; the output of running `$ clinfo` is

```
$ clinfo
Number of platforms                               0
```

For another, the `lspci` program does not appear to notice the cards either; the output of `$ lspci` is the same whether I plug in or unplug the card PCIe risers.

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev d5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation B85 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
```

**Why is my machine appearing to not notice these graphics cards plugged into it?**

I have tried:

- Plugging the cards into different PCIe ports on the motherboard.
- Reinstalling the `amdgpu-pro` card driver.
- In the BIOS settings, changing "Detect Non-Compliance PCI Express Device" from "Disabled" to "Enabled".
- Plugging in just one of the two graphics cards.
- Substituting in different riser cords/plugs.
- Plugging the riser into the PCIe-x16 slot.
- Plugging each card in turn directly into the PCIe-x16 slot.

None of this has affected any change in the output of `clinfo` or `lspci`. I am not sure what to try to continue troubleshooting at this point and any help would be much appreciated.

---

Here is a picture summary of the plugs from my graphics cards to my motherboard and two power supplies.
Power supply #1 is rated at 1300W,
power supply #2 is rated at 900W.

- PCIe plug in motherboard to usb cable

[image: PCIe plug in motherboard to usb cable]

- USB cable and 4-pin power cable to graphics card. (Other end of usb cable plugs to PCIe slot on motherboard, other end of 4-pin power cable plugs via SATA to power cord which plugs 5 pins to power supply #1.)

[image: USB cable and SATA power cable to graphics card]

- SATA cable plugs 5-pins into power supply #1. (Other end plugs to 4-pin power cable into card.)

[image: SATA cable plugs into power supply #1]

- Power cable 8-pin end plugged into graphics card. (Other end is 6-pins and plugs into power supply #2.)

[image: power cable (8-pin end) plugged into graphics card]

- Power cable (6-pin end) plugged into power supply #2. (Other end is 8-pins and plugs into graphics card.)

[image: 6-pin cable plugged into power supply #2]

Comment: Quick questions: 1. how are you connecting the external power (I'm assuming some kind of adapter for at least one of the cards)? 2. Have you tried connecting just one at a time? 3. Are you able to verify there's enough power from the risers for the cards, which are pretty thirsty?

Comment: @WillCrawford thank you for the comment. In response to your questions: (1) I have edited the question adding pictures documenting how the cards are connected to the motherboard and to the power supplies. (2) I tried just one card and output from `$ lspci` remains unchanged. (3) In addition to the motherboard the graphics cards are connected to two power supplies. One graphics card is stated to require a 500W power supply; power supply #1 is rated at 1300W and power supply #2 is rated at 900W.

Comment: Does either card work plugged straight into the motherboard PCIe slot, using the 8-pin power from PSU #2?

Comment: Did you verify that the cards work? Did you try to use the riser on your x16 slot? Did you verify what PCIe version the components require? All five of the PCIe x2 slots are also just PCIe 2.0 and not 3.0.

Comment: @WillCrawford Per your suggestion I tried plugging each card in turn directly into the PCIE-x16 slot while using the 8-pin power from PSU#2, and this caused no change in the output of `$ lspci`.

Comment: @Seth Thank you for the comment. (1) I plugged a card into my laptop via usb, and this caused no change in the output of `$ lspci` on my laptop -- I'm not sure what else I could try to verify that the cards work. One card was purchased new, the other slightly used. (2) I've tried to use the riser in the PCIe-x16 slot, and now have also tried plugging each card into it directly; no change in `$ lspci` output occurred. (3) The cards are listed to support "PCI Express 3.0", and I am reading that PCI 3.0 is backwards compatible with PCI 2.0 so it appears that the PCI versions are compatible.

Comment: Anecdotal I do have a capture card that won't work in 2.0 slots on my Ryzen board only in 3.0 slots. Did you directly plug the cards into the x16 slot to see whenever they actually work? You do list it but just to make sure. If you don't get output from those cards if you attach a display to them and directly plug them into the x16 slot something really is a miss (IMO). In addition why are you using the amdgpu-pro driver? In addition the last picture contains a diagnostic code (it seems) did you check what it means? The blue stuff seems to block the fans?